# Composer installation doesnt work. Connection denied

Tags: php, laravel, installation, composer-php

I wanna install Laravel and for that I need composer. I'm on a new PC so I have to install it again. 
I've got the latest php version and if I want to install composer via the setup exe, I will get an error that the access is denied:

> The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded:
>   failed to open stream: Es konnte keine Verbindung hergestellt werden,
>   da der Zielcomputer die Verbindung verweigerte.

The german roughly part says: "The connection failed, because the computer on the other end denied the connection."

I tried downloading the phar and install it manually, but I get the exact same error in the terminal.

Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 0):

https://getcomposer.org/download/

Download and run **Composer-Setup.exe** - it will install the latest composer version whenever it is executed.

download composer from the above link 
then setup on your system

it will start to work

Comment: I tried that, but I get an error when I use the setup.exe like u see above.

Answer (score -1):

Try downloading .exe https://getcomposer.org/Composer-Setup.exe

Help link
https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows

Comment: "_and if I want to install composer via the setup exe_" OP probably did exactly that

Comment: I tried that, but I get an error when I use the setup.exe like u see above.